# Where do my $PATHS come from on osx?

Tags: macos, path

I KNOW this question it's kind of a duplication, but I think my problem is a bit different than the other questions I found here.

If I echo $PATH, I can see the usual string with several paths. Ok. But I cannot find where they are really written (at least no all):

/private/etc/profile:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

/private/etc/paths:(there are some but not all I can see from the echo!!!)

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

~/.bash_profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

~/.bashrc

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

And I currently don't have any ~/.profile file.

I'm not a unix expert at all. I cannot understand where all the paths come from and so where's the best place to add or modify.

Can you suggest me something? :)

Answer (score 1):

Source [Mastering the path_helper utility of MacOSX](http://www.softec.lu/site/DevelopersCorner/MasteringThePathHelper)

> Aimed to simplify path management, `path_helper`, the new tool
>   introduced in Leopard that help manage the `PATH` environment variable,
>   has probably not be as welcome as it should have been, particularly
>   because it is not well documented. We try to shed some light on this
>   obscure tool.
>
> path_helper is located in `/usr/libexec`. By itself, this tool is
>   harmless, since it does not change anything in your environment, it is
>   just a `bash` or `csh` commands generator for constructing `PATH` and
>   `MANPATH` environment variables based on some text files located in
>   `/etc`. So, try it !
>
> More then thousand words, lets run it:

```
$ /usr/libexec/path_helper
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-2.0.9/bin"; export PATH
MANPATH="/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/X11/man"; export MANPATH
```

> The commands it output are not executed unless you call the same
>   command in an `eval` like what it is done in the `/etc/profile`, which is
>   the default startup script for `bash` shell:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

> But, how does it construct these paths ?
>
> - The `path_helper` utility reads the contents of the files in the directories `/etc/paths.d` and `/etc/manpaths.d` and appends their
>     contents to the `PATH` and `MANPATH` environment variables respectively.
> - Files in these directories should contain one path element per line.

In your example `/private/etc/profile` you have:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

Look in `/etc/paths.d` to see what path elements are being added from this file.

For more information see the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/path_helper.8.html)